# Is a web-scraping software a "wrapper"?

Tags: web-scraping, wrapper, definition

I found that on Google, the definition of a wrapper is *"any entity that encapsulates (wraps around) another item."* also, *"Wrappers are used for two primary purposes: to convert data to a compatible format or to hide the complexity of the underlying entity using abstraction."*

I also know that web-scraping methods are used for extracting data from websites. Does this mean that a web-scraping software is a wrapper? Or have I completely misunderstood the definition of a wrapper?

Comment: You misunderstood the definition.  Wrappers are methods (functions) that call another methods that do the actual work.

Comment: @PM77-1 you're talking about *wrapper functions*, OP is talking about Wrappers in the data mining sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_(data_mining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapper in data mining is a program that extracts content of a particular information source and translates it into a relational form.

Extracting data out of a website can be called web-scraping, however a wrapper will go ahead and perform one more step at "Translating the data pulled into a relational form"

We can say that a wrapper is something that a web-scraping tool might use in order to get more insight about crawled data